# Проблема с командой "laravel new": "laravel не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом"

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

Я пытаюсь создать новый проект Laravel с помощью команды laravel new, но получаю ошибку "laravel не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом". Я установил Laravel CLI с помощью Composer, и установка завершилась без ошибок. Однако, при попытке выполнить команду laravel new, получаю эту ошибку.

Я проверил переменную окружения PATH и убедился, что путь к глобальным пакетам Composer добавлен. Я также убедился, что выполняю команду laravel new в командной строке (терминале), а не в PHP-скрипте. Кроме того, я попытался обновить глобальные пакеты Composer с помощью команды composer global update, но проблема осталась.

Моя операционная система - [Windows]. У меня установлен Composer [ 2.5.7]. Я также использовал Open Server Panel 5.4.3 и все операции проводил через консоль OpenServer'а.

Как я могу исправить эту проблему и успешно создать новый проект Laravel с помощью команды laravel new?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Какой путь в PATH прописан?

Comment: C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_8.1

Comment: Чтобы терминал понимал что такое laravel, надо чтобы в PATH был путь к исполняемому файлу.  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor` где-то тут ищите папку bin, внутри должен быть laravel.exe

Comment: есть laravel.bat

Comment: Добавьте скрин.. Раньше чтобы работала команда нужно было в PATH добавить `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` или `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\laravel`

Comment: создать laravel проект через laravel new получается через терминал windows, а через терминал open server не получается

Comment: В OpenServer есть настройка path, там вроде надо галочку поставить чтобы использовать path винды и должно работать